# Eonasdan DateTimePicker for Bootstrap v4 (Tempus Dominus) Not Working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, eonasdan-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am including and calling it in my Javascript file like this:

```
import 'moment';
import 'tempusdominus-bootstrap-4';

export default class AddHolidayPane {
    static Initialise() {
        $('#start-date').datetimepicker();
        $('#end-date').datetimepicker();
    }
}
```

...and it's giving me this error:

```
tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js?48a1:25 Uncaught Error: Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's requires at least moment.js v2.17.0 but less than v3.0.0
    at Object.eval (tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js?48a1:25)
    at eval (274:2769)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Home.js:1098)
    at __webpack_require__ (Home.js:20)
    at Object.eval (AddHolidayPane.hb.js?45c2:5)
    at eval (186:119)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Home.js:951)
    at __webpack_require__ (Home.js:20)
    at eval (HomeManager.hb.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Home.js:933)
```

It, along with `moment.js` are properly referenced in my `package.json` file ("moment": "2.21.0").

I really have no idea why this error is being thrown given that the seemingly correct version of moment is supplied.

Comment: you may have multiple versions of moment installed

Comment: Just spoke to my colleague and we actually do have multiple versions of moment installed - the other is version 3. We require version 3 because other plugins are dependent on it. Not sure if there's a good way around this.

Comment: see https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have it working is having this in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4": "^5.1.1"
  }
```

in the js then use

```
global.moment = require('moment');
require('tempusdominus-bootstrap-4');

//And then call datetimepicker function

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

should work now.

P.S.: this is for **bootstrap4**